# Bootstrap Nav Module Multi Levels

Tags: joomla-2.5, menu, bootstrap

I'm using [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/bootstrapnav) extention to make my bootstrap menu. It works fine but I can't figure out why my menu doesn't support more than 2 levels (3 atleast). If I add a 3rd level to my submenu, it appears as if it's a 1st level.

It is easier to look at the images bellow:

Menu tree:

[image]

The second level ("two") appears inside first level ("one"), but the third level doesn't show up here.

[image]
[image]

I've searched for `max levels` and `min levels` at the module's definitions but didn't find anything to change it.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: If you want to make a menu with more than 2 levels try smartmenus (without the bootstrap addon).

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap v2.3.2 menu, based on navbar, does not support more than 2 levels: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar